# Convert/Cast String to Integer using Mono for Android

Tags: android, visual-studio-2010, xamarin.android

Easy question, I know.  But failing nonethless!

In C sharp you can simply type:

```
string mystring = "4";

int myint = convert.toint32(mystring);
```

I am getting a Null Unhandled Exception leading me to suspect this does not work using MonoDroid.  So I dug into the API and found the Cast class which supposedly lets you covert between int and string class types.

```
[Android.Runtime.Register("cast", "(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;", "")]
public Object Cast (Object obj)
```

However none of my attempts to utilize the class have worked. The below fails:

```
int myint= Class.Cast(mystring);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Of course this does not work using MonoDroid.

That's not true - since you are using MonoDroid of course the same code works just fine:

```
string mystring = "4";
int myint = Convert.ToInt32(mystring);
```

Comment: You are correct.  A different error in my code was responsible for the Unhandled Exception I was getting.  Just one of those nights, I suppose.